# R- cannot access dr.fit() function

Tags: r, regression

Lately I have been studying dimension reduction using sliced inverse regression .To implement in R ,im using the dr() function from the dr package. When i checked the function body of dr(), there exist a call to dr.fit() inside it which does the major slicing and other computations. I would like to know how to see the body of this dr.fit() function. When i simply type dr.fit in the console ,i get an error that dr.fit object is not found. I also tried with getAnywhere() too.

Comment: Try also dr:::dr.fit

Comment: it wont help. dr.fit wasnt included in the namespace of dr package.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't see `dr.fit` inside the `dr` function (did you mean `dr.compute`?), but if you want to browse the code why don't you download the `dr_3.0.10.tar.gz` package source from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dr/index.html) and browse the code in the R directory.

Comment: Just looked, `dr.fit` is in the dr.R file in the source.